# std::queue included in precompiled header is not part of namespace std

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, precompiled-headers

I have a problem with the inclusion of header "queue" via a precompiled header file in c++ (VS 2019).

My Visual Studio solution consists of two projects, one engine project (static library) and one sandbox project (links the engine project) to test the engine's functionality. The engine project uses a precompiled header file, in which i just included "queue" since i am implementing a message system. Both projects are using C++17.

Visual Studio compiles the engine project without a problem, the sandbox project then throws the following error while compiling:

Error C2039 'queue': is not a member of 'std' (path\to\engine\message_handler.h)

As soon as I include "queue" directly in message_handler.h (see code excerpt), the error vanishes and the project starts up just fine.

I have been using the precompiled header for almost a year now and never had any problems.
Can anyone help me with this?

Following are the relevant excerpts from my code.

Precompiled header:

```
#pragma once
//memory
#include <memory>

//timing
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

//container
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>

//string and streams
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

//misc
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
```

message.h

```
struct Message
{
  Message(){}
  uint32_t id_;
};
```

message_handler.h

```
#pragma once
//#include <queue> //fixes the issue
#include "message.h"

using UnqPtr = std::unique_ptr<Message>; 
class MessageHandler
{
  public:
    MessageHandler();

  private:
    static constexpr uint32_t maxMessages_ = 10000;
    std::queue<UnqPtr<Message>, std::vector<UnqPtr<Message>>> msqQueue_;   
};
```

message_handler.cpp

```
#include "trpch.h" //precompiled header
#include "message_handler.h"

MessageHandler::MessageHandler()
{
  //reserve space in the underlying vector
  std::vector<UnqPtr<Message>> queue;
  queue.reserve(maxMessages_);
  msqQueue_ = std::queue{queue};   
}
```

Comment: whats inside `message.h` and what is `// defined in another file` ?

Comment: Probably the precompiled header is not updating itself even though you have editted it. Compilers sometimes get confused, Just manually delete the `*.pch` file and try again.

Comment: I updated the question to address largest_prime's comment.
@john I cleaned the solution several times and also removed the directories containing the compiled objects. It still doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is some source file that includes either `message.h` or `message_handler.h` does not also include the precompiled header.

Comment: @drescherjm I checked that already and checked it again, they are all including the precompiled header. I am creating new classes via resharper templates, which contains the include for the pch-file. What is really weird to me, that the sandbox project (links the engine project) is producing the error, not the engine project where the code resides and the pch-file is used.

Comment: ***that the sandbox project (links the engine project) is producing the error, not the engine project where the code resides and the pch-file is used*** I expected that. Does the sandbox project use the same exact precompiled header as the engine?

Comment: The sandbox project doesn't use a precompiled header file. There is a engine.h (includes only files from the engine project, no c++ library files) which is included by the sandbox project but the precompiled header is solely used by the engine. Up until I included "queue" it never was a problem.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] project so we can open it and try it out.

Comment: I will put together a minimal example

Comment: ***The sandbox project doesn't use a precompiled header file*** Then it won't benefit from the headers in the precompiled header because its not using them in the sandbox project. My advice  is to fix this by putting `#include <queue>` in `message_handler.h`

Comment: I solved it now by including the pch-file in the engine.h file, which is in turn included by the sandbox project. I am really curious where this behavior is coming from though, since i have been using the pch-file for months now and it never was a problem. Thanks for the different ideas!

Comment: I think you were unlucky that it worked in the past. Probably the sandbox project includes iostream and that brought in most of the system headers for you.